# How can I calculate a date differential in Python across multiple rows and columns?

Tags: python, pyspark, time, group-by, datediff

I'm trying to calculate the differential between the first `Sent` date/time in an ID and the last `Received` date/time in an ID, grouping them by Source and Destination.  Sample (named `test_subset`) looks like this (but it is '000s of rows):

```
| ID   | From | To   | leg_sent | leg_received | Source | Destination |
|:-----|:-----|:-----|:---------|:-------------|:-------|:------------|
| 1btr | ABC  | XYZ  | 08:22:23 | 08:22:41     | GB     | FR          |
| 1btr | XYZ  | DEF  | 08:22:49 | 08:23:05     | GB     | FR          |
| 2vyu | LMN  | JFK  | 14:35:11 | 14:35:23     | US     | DE          |
| 2vyu | JFK  | HIJ  | 14:35:35 | 14:35:48     | US     | DE          |
| 2vyu | HIJ  | TPQ  | 14:35:51 | 14:36:25     | US     | DE          |
```

In the data `ID` is a transfer ID with the `From` and `To` rows being each of the legs of the transfer. In some instances their may be only 2 legs in others there may be as many as 10; what has to be calculated is the difference between first sent and last received, which won't be on the same row.  The `Source` and `Destination` would remain the same across all rows relating to the same ID.

I currently have a piece of code (below) that works for me to calculate the differential between `leg_sent` and `leg_received` on the same row and grouping it by the From and To codes:

```
pairs = (
test_subset
.withColumn('"leg_time"', F.datediff('seconds', F.col('"leg_sent"'), F.col('"leg_received"')))
.groupBy(['"From"', '"To"'])
.agg(
    F.count('*').alias('"num_paths"'),
    F.avg('"leg_time"').alias('"average_leg_time"'),
    F.min('"leg_time"').alias('"min_leg_time"'),
    F.max('"leg_time"').alias('"max_leg_time"')
)
.withColumn('"leg_range"', F.col('"max_leg_time"') - F.col('"min_leg_time"'))
)
```

I need to calculate the full time differential by calculating the difference between first `leg_sent` and last `leg_received` for the same ID and grouping by Source and Destination.  Ideally I want to modify the same code block above to suit this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly to get the full time for the same id, source and destination, I think you can group by `ID`, `Source` and `Destination` and get the `MIN(leg_sent)` and `MAX(leg_received)` and then calculate the difference

```py
pairs = (
test_subset
.groupBy(['"ID"', '"Source"', '"Destination"'])
.agg(
    F.min('"leg_sent"').alias('"min_leg_sent"'),
    F.max('"leg_received"').alias('"max_leg_received"')
)
.withColumn('"leg_full_time"', F.datediff('seconds', F.col('"min_leg_sent"'), F.col('"max_leg_received"')))
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I just switched around "max_leg_received" and "min_leg_sent" on the last line to get the time as a positive value.